# Type Error: No module named 'kivy._clock'

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, kivy, spyder

I installed anaconda under Windows 10. When I want to install kivy with the command:

```
conda install kivy -c conda-forge
```

I have an error message:  impossible to install kivy.

After 3 trials kivy settles normally.

I then tested a basic program (the one in the kivy documentation) in Spyder but I have an error message:

````
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\coll\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-06-17_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\coll\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\src\anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
[ERROR  ] [Clock       ] Unable to import kivy._clock. Have you perhaps forgotten to compile kivy? Kivy contains Cython code which needs to be compiled. A missing kivy._clock often indicates the Cython code has not been compiled. Please follow the installation instructions and make sure to compile Kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\coll\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 4, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App

  File "C:\Users\coll\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 319, in <module>
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp

  File "C:\Users\coll\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.clock import Clock

  File "C:\Users\coll\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 363, in <module>
    from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy._clock'     ```

How to install a full version of kivy with anaconda or replace the missing file plz?
````

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you try install with `pip` - ie. `pip install kivy` or `python -m pip install kivy` ?

Comment: Hello,I updated my message. When I try to install kivy with pip on cmd I have the error: Requirement already satisfied: kivy in c:\users\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (1.11.1)  : kivy is correctly installed

Answer (score 1):

finally I managed to install it with the code line: `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 kivy` on anaconda